# NASM Assembler Floating Point Addition

Tags: assembly, floating-point, nasm, addition, ieee-754

I'm going through Computer Architecture course in my college and we are writing currently NASM codes linked with C. We have a task to code **32-bit IEEE-754 Addition**, i.e 2.0 + 0.1 = 2.1. Requirements are that we can't use Floating Point registers and operators, with the exception of MOVD and xmm0, xmm1.

We've only got some steps as hints to how we should code it, that's all. Im struggling and hope someone could explain me where to start.

As fas as I know, we get the first parameter in xmm0, then move it to general registers, for example:

**MOVD eax, xmm0**

after that we should divide our number into sign, expontent and mantissa using shift operators **(shl,shr)**. I'm stuck at this step. After that we must compare our signs, mantissas and just do the IEEE-754 addition. In theory I know how it works, but have no idea how to code it.

Many thanks for your help!

EDIT:
So I think I've got the first step of it - dividing it in three parts.

```
 ;Mantissa, getting it out of xmm0 and saving in r10d 
MOVD eax, xmm0
shl eax, 9 
mov r10d, eax

;Exponent, savin it in r9d
MOVD eax, xmm0
shr eax,23
shl eax,24
mov r9d, eax

;Sign, saving it in r8d
MOVD eax, xmm0
shr eax,31
shl eax,31
mov r8d, eax
```

Comment: Do you have to only use SHL / SHR to extract, or are bitwise operations (AND / OR / XOR, etc.) also allowed? I seem to get what exactly you misunderstand, and bitwise ops may come in handy to clarify things a bit.

Comment: Whoops, yes! Forgot to mention that. Also I believe I worked out the first step, I'll add it to the post.

Comment: Well, the first step is correct but the exponent could use a brush-up. We\`ll get to this soon. Now please split some second number into three parts, and let\`s add, beginning with the trivial case. What does it take to add two numbers whose signs and exponents are equal?